# flash Actionscript 3 and php image upload

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

recently i am going through a project of badge-builder with action-script and flash.now i need some help for image uploading from the flash interface to the server and showing it back in the flash interface,

the back-end programing language is php and i am using action-scrip 3 and flash cs5

can anyone please give me a right direction how to achieve this job.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the AS3 code, it's just some quick and dirty timeline code:

```
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileRef.addEventListener( Event.SELECT, uploadFile );
fileRef.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, fileUploadProgress );
fileRef.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, fileUploadComplete );

button.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, browseForFile );

function browseForFile( e:Event ):void
{
fileRef.browse();
}

function uploadFile( e:Event ):void
{
fileRef.upload( new URLRequest( "http://localhost/php5dev/test/upload_script.php"  ), "as3File", false );
}

function fileUploadProgress( e:ProgressEvent ):void
{
trace( ( e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal ) * 100 );
}

function fileUploadComplete( e:Event ):void
{
trace( "upload complete" );
}
```

here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$target = "uploads/" . basename( $_FILES[ "as3File" ][ "name" ] );

if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ "as3File" ][ "tmp_name" ], $target ) )
    echo( "file upload success<bt />" );
else
    echo( "error uploading file<br />" );
```

?>

Hope this helps, let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

Comment: yes yes its working still the product is in production mode just 2 nd day here is the link you can check

http://sunmicrosoft.com/badgebuilder/

thank you very much for you help

Answer (score 0):

use the FileReference AS3 class to get a file into Flash, then use the FileReference.upload() method to send the file to a php script that will put the file on the server.
Once that is done, do a URLRequest on the uploaded file to display it back in Flash.
This is just the theory, I can add code if you need some help with that.

Comment: yes that will be very helpfull because i am quite new in actionscript thing.

Thank you for your answer and help.

Answer (score 0):

yes yes its working still the product is in production mode just 2 nd day  here is the link you can check

http://sunmicrosoft.com/badgebuilder/

thank you very much for you help