# Saving an image from Flash on the server under different name

Tags: actionscript-3, filereference

I followed this question:
[flash Actionscript 3 and php image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258845/flash-actionscript-3-and-php-image-upload)
I copied the code:

```
 function uploadFile( e:Event ):void
{
fileRef.upload( new URLRequest( "http://localhost/php5dev/test/upload_script.php"  ), "as3File", false );
}
```

and

```
<?php

$target = "uploads/" . basename( $_FILES[ "as3File" ][ "name" ] );

if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ "as3File" ][ "tmp_name" ], $target ) )
    echo( "file upload success<bt />" );
else
    echo( "error uploading file<br />" );
?>
```

It works great, I just need to know how to save the image under a specific name, how do I pass an argument to the php script? or is that not necessary, can I change it before calling the script?

---

How would I then call URLrequest to show user the file he uploaded ?
Thanks, for any answers!

Answer (score 1):

You could send the filename via a GET query:

```
fileRef.upload( new URLRequest( "http://localhost/php5dev/test/upload_script.php?filename=myFile.txt"  ), "as3File", false );
```

And then retrieve it in PHP as $_GET['filename'];

As a word of advice, be careful with those scripts since they are very insecure (one could upload any file to your server and exploit it very easily).

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I though when I have it like thisfileRef.browse([new FileFilter("Images", ".jpg;.jpeg;*.gif;*.png")]); User can only upload images, is this assumption correct?

Comment: Through *your* swf file sure, but I could call your PHP script from anywhere (I could create a new SWF for instance) and upload anything I wanted anywhere I wanted in your server (i.e. if you don't secure it, I could send ?filename=../../../index.php and it could overwrite your main index file)... So yeah, be very careful, and if this is for a live project, I would recommend to hire a backend guy to secure this kind of server-side scripts ;)